# Using operator() in member functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I overloaded the operator () in one of my classes and I would like to use it in another member function.

```cpp
class A {
public:
    void operator()();
    void operator()(double x);
};

void A::operator()() {
    // stuff
};

void A::operator()(double x) {
    // stuff with other members and x
    this->operator();
};
```

The line `this->operator()` does not work. I just want to use the operator I defined as a member function of my class `A`. The error I get is : `Error  1   error C3867: 'A::operator ()': function call missing argument list; use '&A::operator ()' to create a pointer to member`

Comment: did you try `(*this)()` instead?

Answer (score 9):

You should write:

```
void A::operator()(double x) {
    // stuff with other members and x
    this->operator()();
};
```

The first `()` are the name of the operator, and the second are for the call itself: that's the missing (empty) argument list from the error message.

Comment: Edited. It was a copy/paste issue, my problem being about using operator() in another member function.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for calling member function on pointer-to-object is:

```
ptr->memberName();
```

In your case member name is `operator()`, so you want to write

```
ptr->operator()();
```

or for the other variant

```
ptr->operator()(1.0);   // operator() accepting single argument of type double
```

The same goes for defining the `operator()` - you're missing one pair of parenteses everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb:

The name of an operator-overloading function is **always** `operator@`, with `@` being the overloaded operator.

To call an operator-overload-function directly by its name, type `operator@(params)`, in your case, `operator() (...)`.